# WPF: ContentTemplate of ContentControl is always null

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

I have a ContentControl bound to an instance of class X and a DataTemplate for X in the resource section of the Main Window.

```
<Window x:Class="DT1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DT1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:X}">
            <TextBlock Text="Hello, World!"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="Press me" Click="Button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <ContentControl x:Name="cont" Background="Pink" Content="{Binding MyX}" Tag="Blobby"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In the button click handler in the MainWindow code behind I have a handler which tries to access the ContentTemplate of the ContentControl but this is always null:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace DT1
{
    public class X
    {
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public X MyX { get; set; } = new X();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var template = cont.ContentTemplate;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"ContentTemplate: {template?.ToString() ?? "template is null"}");
        }
    }
}
```

What is the right way to access the visual items in the DataTemplate for X?

Answer (score 0):

It is null because you are not setting any datatemplate **explicitly**. When you define a datatemplate without providing an **x:key** and providing a DataType using **x:Type** you are making use of what it is known as **Implicit Datatemplates**.

In order to get the datatemplate from codebehind you must assign it explicitly:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:X}" x:Key="XTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="Hello, World!"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="Press me" Click="Button_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <ContentControl x:Name="cont" Background="Pink" Content="{Binding MyX}" Tag="Blobby" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource XTemplate}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. That is actually useful to know, but is there any way to access the elements of the template when using implicit DataTemplates? Implicit DataTemplates are very useful because you can very easily change the representation of a type by changing the template.

Comment: I have the same problem. I don't set a x:Key for the DataTemplate because my listbox has items with different types. So I should set only DateType to my dataTemplates. Do you have any idea for this situation?

Comment: @DadkhahDadkhah Would be interesting to know what you are actually trying to do...maybe there is a better way to achieve it.